# this property overflow:visible makes to double click an element?

Tags: css

The part of the `overflow:visible` code does need to double click on the item to be activated,someone knows why?

```
input:focus,select:focus{
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ed1c24;
    outline: 0;
    color:#444444;
    font-size:11px; 
    overflow:visible;
    font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

here an example with more code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        input:focus,select:focus{
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ed1c24;
        outline: 0;
        color:#444444;
        font-size:11px; 
        overflow:visible; 
        font-family:"Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text">
    <select name="prueba" id="">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give more details with all code .

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you're asking. If English is not your first language, please have someone assist you in translating.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* There's not enough info in your question to tell why your input needs to be double clicked to get the focus. You need to include enough code to duplicate the issue.

Comment: @zzzzBov Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @zzzzBov Sorry for my bad english. the part of the code that I mention `overflow:visible`, it causes the double-click on the item, for example to a select I have to double click to make the list is displayed and I have to also double click to be able to write to an input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need overflow visible on focus. See below:

```css
input:focus,
select:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ed1c24 inset;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ed1c24;
  outline: 0;
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<select name="prueba" id="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the `:focus` pseudo-class. The focus means, that the `overflow:visible;` applies only when the `input` or `select` gain focus (by clicking on it).